# Showing check box values in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following collection_select in the new and edit pages to let users select contacts and associate them to a group:

```
<%= f.label :contacts %>
    <div><span class="ul">
      <% current_user.contacts.all.each do |contact| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "contacts[]", contact.id %>
      <%= f.label contact.name %>
      <% end %></div>
    </span>
```

I would like to show the already selected contacts checked in the edit page of the group. Is there another parameter that I can use along with the check_box_tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can just pass in a true/false after the value](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

```
<%= f.label :contacts %>
  <div>
    <span class="ul">
      <% current_user.contacts.all.each do |contact| %>
        <% checked_logic = some logic for true/false %>
        <%= check_box_tag "contacts[]", contact.id, checked_logic %>
        <%= f.label contact.name %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  </div> 
<% end %>
```